# Empty Child in model, Null when saved with References<>

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, reference, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an object declared like this

```
public class MyObject
{
    public virtual long MyId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyChild Child { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        Child = new MyChild();
    }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public virtual long MyId { get; set; }
}
```

I am setting the child with an "empty object" because I want an empty object instead of a null in my model.

In my database I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE MyObjects
(
    MyObjectId    bigint    IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ChildId       bigint    NULL
)
```

And then I have in my mapping

```
References<MyChild>(x => x.Child, "ChildId");
```

Here's where the problems set in.  When I try to create a new `MyObject`, I will get an error **object references an unsaved transient instance**.  So, I did this:

```
var newObject = new MyObject()
{
    Child = null
};

repository.Save(newObject);
```

This works to save, but now my object has a null child, which isn't the behavior I want.  The hack I could use is to reset the child to empty after creating the new `MyObject`, but I want to see if there is a better way.

Child needs to be not null in my object, but saved as null if the ID of the child object is 0.

**EDIT**

Was just testing out the whole null/reset strategy and it doesn't work.  subsequent nhibernate requests to any objects in my model cause the transient object error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have different behavior for normal and persistence use. You could implement your own entitypersistor, but this would require a lot of effort. I prefer workarounds in such situations, because this violates the assumtions NHibernate has.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public virtual long MyId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyChild Child { get; set; }

    protected /*internal*/ virtual MyChild ChildForPersisting
    {
        get { return (MyChild.Id == 0) ? null : Child; }
        set { if (value != null) Child = value; }
    }

    public MyObject()
    {
        Child = new MyChild();
    }
}

// with internal
References(x => x.ChildForPersisting, "ChildId")

// without internal
References(Reveal.Member<MyChild>("ChildForPersisting"), "ChildId")
```

another option would be to implement before and after save eventlistener which null/resets the child object, but still a lot of effort.

Comment: I did a version of your suggestion. I used a private local variable and my property returns a new instance of the child if the property is null, after setting the local property to the new instance.  I let my parent object save "empty" children, and then update them when the user enters the appropriate data.